# Dynamically setting the <T> when calling a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am having an issue trying to recursively use a generic function for a deserialization algorithm. I am loading in the variables from an XElement by their value. However, if they are no a primitive, I have to recursively do the same operation on that object. However, that object is not the same type as the current one being processed. So for instance if I have

```
 class someObject
 {
      otherObject obj = new otherObject();
 }

 class otherObject
 {
     int someInt = 123;
 }
```

the deserializer recursively goes into the other object. However, the issue is that I have to change the type of the generic method dynamically (ie. I do not know what type it will be at compile time). The algorithm is as follows:

```
public static T deserialize<T>(XNode element)
    where T : new()
{
    XElement currentNode = (XElement)element;

    FieldInfo[] fields = getFields<T>();

    T returnValue = new T();

    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (field.FieldType.IsPrimitive)
        {
            field.SetValue(returnValue, currentNode.Element(field.Name).Value);
        }
        else
        {
            //The issue is on the following line
            field.SetValue(returnValue, deserialize<???>(currentNode.Element(field.Name).Value));
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen plenty of documentation on how to dynamically create typed lists and objects. However, I cannot find anything that deals with dynamically switching the type on a generic method call.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if am not being clear...

Comment: Templates are C++. These are generics.

Comment: So if you don't know what it's going to be at compile time, how is your routine going to know at runtime?  Does you XElement have an attribute with a flag of the Type stored as the value?

Comment: It has a fieldType which lets me know what type it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the generic method call another private non-generic method that uses a different means of creating the instance instead of `new T()`. The outer generic method will be convenient for a caller of the method, so they don't have to cast the response. Internally, your code will be simpler.

Note that the .NET framework's deserialisation methods all at least have overloads that take a `Type` instance instead of a generic type parameter (`<T>`). This is for the reason you're discovering -- sometimes you have the type as an object, and then you can't (sensibly) call a generic method and pass that type parameter.

Comment: Good point, having a Type parameter will probably be more straight forward and will still allow for recursion. I've gotten into the habit of using new T() on simple objects because it shortens up the code and makes it easier to read (but it does force them to do <someObject>()). I think you have the right idea.

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` isn't much worse than `new T()`, and is significantly better than the reflection approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you have to mark the class with attributes DataContract, DataMember

```
   static readonly XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    };


    static XElement ToXElement<T>(T obj)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type valorType = obj.GetType();
        using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.Create(sb, ws))
        {
            DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            s.WriteObject(writer, obj);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        return XElement.Parse(sb.ToString());
    }

    static T ToObj<T>(XElement node)
    {
        string xml = node.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);      
        T respuesta = default(T);
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (StringReader strReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader))
            {
                respuesta = (T)dcs.ReadObject(xmlReader, false);
            }
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
```

Test:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class A
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Prop { get; set; }
    }

        var node = ToXElement(12);
        int obj = ToObj<int>(node);


        var node2 = ToXElement(new A { Prop = 12 });
        A obj2 = ToObj<A>(node2);
```